# puppeteer download firefox and chrome binaries together

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, npm, puppeteer

I´am able to download firefox binaries for my project by set the environment variable:

```sh
npm config set PUPPETEER_PRODUCT firefox npm i puppeteer
```

Then inside of my project I run:

```sh
npm i puppeteer
```

This works fine. However when I change it back to chrome and reinstall it:

```sh
npm config set PUPPETEER_PRODUCT chrome npm i puppeteer
npm i puppeteer
```

It will delete the firefox binaries and only install chrome again. I tried to run **npm update** after switching the **PUPPETEER_PRODUCT** environment variable however this doesn´t work and nothing gets updated.

How can I download firefox and chrome binaries together? That I can easily switch the product value?

```js
client = await puppeteer.launch({  product: 'firefox'  }); // or product: 'chrome'
```

Please notice that I can not just create a hello world project and set **product: 'firefox'** because the binaries does not exist and will not automatically downloaded. For any default puppeteer install only the chrome binaries will exist.

Switching to firefox won´t work until you change the environment variable **PUPPETEER_PRODUCT** to **firefox** and reinstall puppeteer and download the firefox binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems you can only not use on windows this command via terminal:

- PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install puppeteer

On linux you can run the command above and it will download the binaries. There is actually no need to use this on linux:

- npm config set PUPPETEER_PRODUCT firefox npm i puppeteer

Answer (score 1):

To install both Chromium and Firefox at the same time:

1. Install Chromium

   ```
   npm install puppeteer
   ```
2. Install Firefox

   ```
   cd node_modules/puppeteer
   PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox node install.js
   cd ../..
   ```

You should now see that they're both installed:

```
$ ls -1d node_modules/puppeteer/.local*
node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium
node_modules/puppeteer/.local-firefox
```

Source: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5743#issuecomment-621664876

Answer (score 0):

to install

```bash
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm install puppeteer
```

to change product to existing puppeteer project

```bash
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox npm rebuild
```

available product (choose one)

```
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=firefox
PUPPETEER_PRODUCT=chrome
```

to switch between product

```js
const firefox = await puppeteer.launch({  product: 'firefox'  });
const chrome  = await puppeteer.launch({  product: 'chrome'  });
```